# How to create a selectable map for a board game in Unity3D?

Tags: c#

I'm starting with a board game in Unity like Risk, programming in C#, and I need a selectable world map to put the armies on each region and make it the game board. I have a Raycasting function to select each country but I need to know how to build the board and make the countries selectable.

I have a board like this: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-vtEHvcmS-Ac/TtHk0IvsxoI/AAAAAAAAAnw/V6e_eGfmCac/s1600/Risk+II+Game+Board.jpg

And I want to be able to select the countries separately, like they're objects on their own. Do you know any ways to do that?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, I would take that image, and flood-fill every country with a different color.

Remember the color -> country mapping for later.

If your mouse cursor moves, check in the colored image for the color of the pixel under the mouse cursor, and you can look up the country your mouse hovers over.

To highlight the country graphically, you could also use the colored image to find out which pixels belong to a country, and give them a "selected" color on your screen.